# Adding vector layer over WMS using OpenLayers?

Tags: openlayers, vector, web-mapping

I'm trying to add vector layer to my map from a GeoJSON file stored in the same directory as my maps index.html. However, it won't work.

Is there something wrong with my syntax?

My code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <style>
      .map {
        height: 600px;
        width: 100%;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <title>Map of San Diego</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>My Map</h2>
    <div id="map" class="map"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var map = new ol.Map({
        target: 'map',
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.MapQuest({layer: 'sat'})
          })
          new ol.layer.Vector({
            source: new ol.source.Vector(casinos.geojson)
          })  
        ],

        view: new ol.View({
          center: ol.proj.transform([-117.128986, 32.985368], 'EPSG:4326', 'EPSG:3857'),
          zoom: 10
        })
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you say: 'It wont work', what exactly do you mean? what do you see? do you get any error?

Answer (score 2):

I think:

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector(casinos.geojson)
})
```

should be something like:

```
new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.GeoJSON({
        url: 'casinos.geojson'
    })
})
```

you may need to account for its projection as well.

```
url: 'casinos.geojson',
projection: 'EPSG:3857'  (or whatever it is)
```